# How can decompile and see Nuget package dll source code using ILSpy

Tags: dll, nuget, ilspy

I have install some asp.net core mvc dlls (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstraction.dll). I want to decompile it and see the source code. 
The dll is added to my project>Dependencies>Nuget.

However, I am not sure where exactly the dll in in my system.

Is there a quick way to just launch the added dll in ILSypy and see the codes or at least the object inheritance tree?

Thanks.

Comment: It is never going to be "quick" when you can't find the DLL.  Do consider [using the source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Abstractions/src).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core is open source, so as Hans wrote as a comment to your question, you can look directly at the source, you don't need to decompile.

But for future reference, NuGet dlls are extracted to one of two places. Older projects still using packages.config, the dlls are typically extracted to a folder named `packages` as a sub-folder of where the `.sln` file is.

Packages using `PackageReference`, the packages are extracted to your account's global packages folder, which by default is `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` on Windows and `~/.nuget/packages` on Linux and Mac. You can also look at your project's `obj\project.assets.json` file to find the paths to everything referenced.

All paths can be modified with `nuget.config` settings (or even msbuild properties for projects using PackageReference). But if this is the case, either you, or your team mate would probably know, so the default locations for the folders I listed above should be correct.